# Error while connecting to AKS via Azure Cli from PowerShell

Tags: azure

while connecting with Azure kubernetes cluster from windows via powershell, I am getting an error.

The command being used is -

```
az aks get-credentials --name clustername --resource-group rgname --subscription subsId
```

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

```
'name'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\knack\knack\cli.py", line 206, in invoke
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 578, in execute
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 636, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 629, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\six\six.py", line 693, in reraise
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 606, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 305, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 485, in default_command_handler
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 1693, in aks_get_credentials
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 2422, in _print_or_merge_credentials
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 1063, in merge_kubernetes_configurations
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qdpilz60\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 1012, in _handle_merge
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: I guess the problem is your Azure CLI. You can try to reinstall the CLI or update it. Then try again.

Comment: yep, I'd start there. it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: Any more update for the question? Do you try the advice in the comment?

Comment: I tried reinstalling but that didn't help, the same error prompted again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when your ~/.kube/config is structured differently than what `az aks get-credentials` expects, for example when certain keys are missing. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10812

You can resolve this issue by deleting ~/.kube/config.

Comment: yeah I got that sorted long time ago.